# create a keyboard shortcut to an R function on mac?

Tags: macos, r, shell, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to create a keyboard shortcut to run an R function in an existing R session. How can I do this on a Mac?

My first idea was to use

% R --slave < foo.R

and create a keyboard-shortcut to a shell script with this command.

But this starts a new R session. Is there a way to send a command to an existing session from shell?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the command does, including inputs and outputs? Are these small enough that they could be accessed (and modified) from files every time you run R via a --slave session?

Comment: Thanks. The kind of function I have in mind is one that has a counter as an input that gets incremented and then does something like produce a plot, say from the i'th row of a big digital image, returning i+1. So, I don't want to start a new session and read everything again, but rather keep the current session running.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two similar ways to do this; neither is necessarily elegant, but both get the job done.

- Run a tmux session which consists solely of an R session, and write a script that uses `tmux send-keys` to send your command.
- Similarly, you could set up a dedicated iTerm2 session to receive the keys. If you were in iTerm2 already, you could set up a keyboard shortcut to send your command. Outside iTerm2, I think you're looking at some applescript.